# How can I place images on top of content overlaying several divs, and keeping it fixed there?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How is this possible, while keeping is responsive? Is this possible at all? I'm referring to websites like this - http://www.behance.net/gallery/Home-Caf-Project/8907125 - look at the coffee beans how it overlays two sections and overtop of the image. stuff like that.. how is that possible? How can it stay fixed regardless of resolution and how does it scale down? Maybe it's just hidden with CSS when it scales to a certain res?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I,don't get your question. The example you give has nothing that scales or is responsive. The coffee beans I see are just part of the background image. Not sure what you are asking exactly...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by assigning higher z-index value to the image you want on top. To keep it fixed you have to change the position to be absolute.

Something like this: http://jsbin.com/arolem/1/

Answer (score 0):

also if you want to keep it responsive set the width of the image to be a percentage of the parent container so when the parent container scales down so do the images in it.